# How to get data from an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to get value of two variables outside a class but I’m not having any luck on it.

I have something like this:

```
class AttentionDataPoint(DataPoint):
    def __init__(self, _dataValueBytes):
        DataPoint.__init__(self, _dataValueBytes)
        self.attentionValue = self._dataValueBytes[0] 

    def __str__(self):
        return "Attention Level: " + str(self.attentionValue)

class MeditationDataPoint(DataPoint):
    def __init__(self, _dataValueBytes):
        DataPoint.__init__(self, _dataValueBytes)
        self.meditationValue = self._dataValueBytes[0]
```

I tried with:

```
Att = AttentionDataPoint()
Value = Att.__init__(attentionValue)
```

And the same for the other same variable but python asks me for a missing positional argument: `_dataValueBytes` but I’m really not able to fix the problem.

The Data Point class is:

```
Class DataPoint:  
    def __init__(self, dataValueBytes):    
        self._dataValueBytes = dataValueBytes
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please, and format your code as such.

Comment: Have you tried `value = AttentionDataPoint(attentionValue)`?

Comment: Yes I tried but it says:  ' __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: "dataValueBytes"' for Att = AttentionDataPoint()

Comment: Please show the exact error message.

Comment: My fault. It says:  value = AttentionDataPoint(attentionValue) NameError: name 'attentionValue' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

When you write down :

```
Att = AttentionDataPoint()
```

You are creating an instance of that class, if you look at the init function of that class, you will see that it requires an argument in order to initiliaze (DataValueBytes).

When you create an instance it automatically call the init function, and I think that is where you confusion is coming from (You dont need to explicitly call it later on).

After initiliazing the class all you need to do in order to access the variable is :

```
Att.attentionValue
```

Comment: Perfect, I just understood that what am I doing is nosense. So, someone could help me on how to get "self.attentionValue" data out from there? I know, I must read and study python, but I am not a programmer and this part of software is only a little part on my project. So if someone could be able to do this it would be great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `attentionValue` is the initial value  you want to pass to `__init__`, you would call it like this:

```
att = AttentionDataPoint(data)
```

When you call the class like this, `self` is automatically passed as the first positional parameter. When you call `__init__` directly as in your second example you only pass one parameter which python assigns to `self`, thus it complains about the missing `_dataValueBytes` parameter.

I can't say what `data` is supposed to be. Whatever you pass is mapped to `_dataValueBytes` inside the class, so maybe that name will give you a clue what it expects.

Once you are able to properly construct the object, getting the data out is very simple, as it's a simply lookup of the attribute:

```
att_value = att.attentionValue
```

Comment: When I write something like what you posted the system says:  NameError: name attentionValue is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: @MarzioRanno: I don't know. Your example showed you trying to use that variable. I have no idea what you expect to pass in.

Comment: I really don’t know. I just want to get the current value of attentionValue from its class, but what i just tried has not effect.

Comment: @MarzioRanno: the code you show us includes values that are _instance_ attributes, not _class_ attributes, so to get them you must first create an _instance_. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: Ok perfect, someone could help me on it? I don’t know why but I’m trying to create an istance without success. Could you help me in how to get those datas please?

Comment: @MarzioRanno: there's no way we can show you how to create an instance of your class with any more detail than the answer already show. . It's your class, and we don't know what the inputs are supposed to be. My answer shows you exactly how to create the instance, it's up to you to know what data you must pass to it.

Comment: I Added the DataPoint class, could help this to reach a point?